# Is it possible to design a recursion to control output results?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Update:  My trouble is in conceptually understanding how to implement it. For example(not as exact as my solution below), I figure out the max range deviation of each value in my list, maybe for 5,3,2 it would be 4-6,2-4,1-3..I can't figure out what to do with that range so my recursion only proceses that. I can do this with nested for loops but recursions are being a little tricky.

I have two parts of my code working. One that generates values(recursively) and one that returns a score(which I only care about solutions that exceed a certain threshold).  Both work(see code below).   The problem is in integrating them as I realize I can't simply refer to the method that controls it because the recursion still generates many results.  I think I need to change my recursion code to somehow incorporate the logic of my similar method(the one that returns a score).

The recursion method takes a list and a integer and tries to figure out all the unique ways the values in the sum can be multiplied to equal the sum(if you send a list of values, 5,3,2 and a target sum of `100`. The formula is calculating is `5x + 3y + 2z = 100`, solve for all the possible values of x, y and z. This is the case in the example code below, if you run it you'll get the full result set).  My problem is I don't need most of the results only ones that match certain characteristics. I created a method(and plan to create more) to limit the results but I'm not sure how to design the recursive method that will allow me to save time and not calculate results I don't need.

Here's an example output based on a small subset of the results.  Currently, I get all the results THEN I filter and remove specific results but that means I first have to create a very large dataset(most of which I do not need). Here's a possible output(not the complete output as there are too many results and I'm doing this manually):

```
Initial list of values [5, 3, 2]
initial list of quantities: [6.0, 8.0, 23.0]. 

// (5*6)+(3*8)+(2*23)=100 as do all examples below but I only want to include 
//the ones with scores above 90(see similar method in my code to see how I get this score)  

[0.0, 0.0, 50.0] // score = 0.7120763990222406 < -- should not be included
[0.0, 2.0, 47.0] // score = 0.7454415587728428 < -- should not be included
[1.0, 11.0, 31.0] // score = 0.9010050506338834 < -- should be included
[1.0, 13.0, 28.0] // score = 0.9133974596215562 < -- should be included
[1.0, 29.0, 4.0] // score = 0.7124239231090319 < -- should not be included
```

I want to figure out a way to avoid generating the ones that should not be included, in the first place.

Hope that makes sense.  Here's the code(the first method, `findVariables`,  generates the results using a list/sum and the second, `similar`, is an example of a control function which I have no clue how to integrate). If i'm not explaining it correctly I think reviewing the two methods will make what I'm doing clear.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class findVariables {

```
public static void findVariables(double[] constants, double sum, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ranges) {
    findVariables0(constants, sum, new double[constants.length], 0, ranges);
}

private static void findVariables0(double[] constants, double remaining, double[] variables, int n, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ranges) {
    //System.out.println();
    if(n == constants.length - 1) {
        // solution if the remaining is divisible by the last constant.
        if (remaining % constants[n] == 0) {
            variables[n] = remaining/constants[n];
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(variables));
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = ranges.get(n).get(0), limit = (int) (remaining/constants[n]); i <= ranges.get(n).get(1); i++) {
            variables[n] = i;
            findVariables0(constants, remaining - i * constants[n], variables, n+1, ranges);
        }
    }
}

private static void similar(HashMap<String, Integer> list1, HashMap<String, Integer> list2) {

    //TODO: This is currently Euclidean Distance, change it to pearson score as it protects from grade inflation, same logic
    //TODO: assess the logic here.  My logic is all the sums are the same, then I can get an accurate difference by simply studying the differences in values they in common
    System.out.println("hello from simlair method. Hopefully I don't crash or worst..turn evil :-)");
    double runsum = 0.0;
    List<String> keys_in_common = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : list1.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if (list2.containsKey(key)) {
            keys_in_common.add(key);
        }
    }

    Iterator it=keys_in_common.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
      String value=(String)it.next();

      //System.out.println("Value :"+value);
      runsum += Math.pow((list1.get(value) - list2.get(value)),2);
      //System.out.println(runsum);
    }
    double score = Math.pow(runsum, .5);
    double score_percent = (100-score)*.01;
    System.out.println(score_percent);


}

public static void main(String... args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> list1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> list2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    list1.put("a", 5);
    list1.put("b", 3);
    list1.put("c", 2);

    list2.put("a", 3);
    list2.put("b", 3);
    list2.put("c", 2);

    //Trying to capture the range around [6.0, 8.0, 23.0] so creating a list of list of values to keep within the range
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOlists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> singleList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    singleList1.add(4);
    singleList1.add(8);
    listOlists.add(singleList1);
    ArrayList<Integer> singleList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    singleList2.add(6);
    singleList2.add(10);
    listOlists.add(singleList2);
    ArrayList<Integer> singleList3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    singleList3.add(20);
    singleList3.add(25);
    listOlists.add(singleList3);

    System.out.println(listOlists);

    similar(list1, list2);
    findVariables(new double[]{5, 3, 2}, 100, listOlists);

}
```

}

My ultimate goal is to have a few thousand variables with large sums and using various type of methods like this to control the results from going too large.

Thanks! Also, as mentioned, I'm very very new to java and I'm sure I'm making mistakes.  I welcome tips and suggestions on how to improve. You can see my desired output and my current code but I'm totally happy to change my entire approach if better so don't feel that your suggestions need to be within the context of my existing code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Going off of our comments, here's an idea:

add a list of pairs to your findVariables0 function as an argument that has the ranges as the two values - e.g.

```
(4,6)
```

to represent a range of 4-6 - let's call the list "ranges". The, in the loop

```
        for (int i = 0, limit = (int) (remaining/constants[n]); i <= limit; i++) {
            variables[n] = i;
            findVariables0(constants, remaining - i * constants[n], variables, n+1);
        }
```

set

```
i = ranges[n].getFirst();" // should be (4)
```

and add a condition value

```
&& i < ranges[n].getSecond(); i++) // should be 6
```

This should limit your recursion to the ranges you want.

**End edit**

From what I can tell,what you're saying in your code right now is:

- Get all the possible solutions to a polynomial with n variables;
- From that set of solutions, select ones that are geometrically close to a point I offer.

And you want to incorporate that second statement in the first, saying:

- Look at a point I offer, and get solutions to a polynomial that are close to that point.

If not, then I've misunderstood.

If I'm on to you, then: since - at least, in your current code - you'll be running through all of the solutions anyway, you might want to look at instead generating the list of HashMaps close to your suggested HashMap, then just checking all of them. Depending on your definition of "close", this might cut out a lot of extra possibilities, seeing as (if I remember my math correctly) a 3-polynomial solution that sums at 100 has 100^3 different possibilities, and 90% of 100^3 is a lot - though you do a good job cutting out a lot of them with the "remaining/constants[n]" line in your current code.

Sadly, I'm not good enough with the math side to help you with an exact algorithm, but I hope I've put you on the path to one. Keep in mind that you may not be able to get all of your optimizations to play well with other optimizations, so you may have to end up choosing between some as opposed to others.

On a good note, I have a few other notes that I hope can help:

Except for where you "score" things, I don't really see the need to make everything a double - the one time you do division, you cast it as an Int anyway, so it'd be best to make them all Integers, I'd think - save memory and whatnot.

Why are the arrays passed to "similar" HashMaps? You essentially iterate through them like arrays, and you'll always be comparing lists of the same size (right? I could be misunderstanding), so there's no need to go through the extra hassle of storing the data with keys, then pulling it out again by running through all the keys in order.

It's easier/ clearer to see

```
runsum += Math.pow((list1[n] - list2.get[n]),2);
```

than all of the HashMapstuff - and it's still O1 access time. I'm not sure what storing them in HashMaps does for you.

Good luck! Hope I've helped.

Comment: You have got my problem exactly correct. My trouble is in conceptually understanding how to implement it.  For example(not as exact as my solution above), I figure out the max range deviation of each value in my list, maybe for 5,3,2 it would be 4-6,2-4,1-3..I can't figure out what to do with that range so my recursion only proceses that.  I can do this with nested for loops but recursions are being a little tricky.

Comment: Well, let's look at a base case - a single variable polynomial with one solution, like 2n = 10. Let's make your suggested list [4], and keep your "90%" definition of close.


(I hit enter by accident - I'll update when I'm finished)

Comment: (continued)


As far as I know , you won't be able to limit your recursion to certain ranges easily. One option is to seed your recursion: since you know you'll want things starting at 3, call
findVariables0 explicitly, starting n at 3 - this way, you skip the first two repetitions.

Alternatively, just try checking 3,4, and 5 in a loop instead of in recursion, as you mention - you'll end up cutting out a lot of computation that way, as well. You might also be able to pass your range (say, 4 through 6) in an additional list of pairs to findVariables0, and then use that list to set i and limit

Comment: Awesome! thank you, I feel I'm getting closer except there is two slight problems.  One is when I run the code above(updated with your suggestions) the first two run within the range I set but the last number runs outside the range(20-25 but I get values using 18,19,etc.).  Also I was wondering how can I deal with numbers not included in the range. Say I have the exact example of above(3 lists in a list) but I have 5 variables to scan from, would it include the 3 ranges within the overall 5 variables(which I want) or ignore everything other than the 3 ranges(which I do not want).

Comment: For debugging your current code, throw it up on [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com), and I'll download eclipse and take a look. (I'm more of a C/python guy)

I hit enter early, so I'll write a second comment for your second question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in your second question. :P

If you take a polynomial with 4 variables, like v + 2x + 3y + 4z, you'll want a list of 4 pairs, a range for each variable; if you take a polynomial with 6 variables, you'd want a list with a range of 6, etc. Then, you'd access each in a row. Which numbers are the ones you think you're missing?

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be asking for is a method for pruning entire sections of the search tree.

If you think of the triplets as points in 3-space, with the target triplet (the one from which you calculate distance) at the origin, your "distance" criterion defines a sphere of some radius.  You could prune any sections of the tree where you could determine, based on ONE or TWO coordinates that the point was outside the sphere.

Let's say the sphere radius (maximum distance) is 10, then any point having any coordinate >10 would necessarily be outside the sphere, and that entire branch of the recursive search tree could be pruned.  Same goes for two coordinates where sqrt(x^2 + y^2) > 10.

Note that this applies for the Euclidean distance.  If you change the distance algorithm you'll have to adjust, and depending on the shape of the distance boundary in 3-space this method may or may not work.

Comment: Thank you Jim.  I'll study your answer, I'm a bit of a beginner so it'll take me time, but I'm not trying to remove entire sections(I can already do that using my similar method and a for loop of all the results).  I'm trying to figure out a way of not wasting cpu time to generate those results in the first place. I'm sorry if thats what you actually are explaining so I'll research what your saying more and try to incorporate it into my code above..

Comment: By "pruning" I mean not going down that branch at all, thereby saving work.  If you can determine, based on ONE of the three values, that a point could never be close enough regardless of the other two values, then all points containing that value can be ignored. Whenever your algorithm generates such a point, then you can immediately return and not investigate any other possibilities containing that value.

Comment: I did think about that and my question was sort of trying to get the practical application of this answer.  I thought about pre calculating what values for each of the values would push me out of the 90% range but was not sure how to design the recursion to support that.  I think it def. has to do with how the for loops are written but I couldln't figure out the algo to do that.